# Octomap + Rosjava?

Tags: octomap, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, sorry if the question is a foolishness. I am going to substitute Player (which I use with PlayerClient) by ROS (which I ment to use with Rosjava).

In the current implementation I use a custom-defined map type, but I need to change it by Octomap. I know that there is a Octomap plugin to use with ROS, but I need to know if it is possible to recover the map using Rosjava and obtain information about it.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134926/octomap-+-rosjava?/) by [AdrianGonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12721/adriangonzalez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can receive the octomap message with rosjava and interpret the information yourself. However the octomap library itself that makes this usable is written in C++.

AFAIK there are no java bindings.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianGonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12721/adriangonzalez/) on 2014-05-05**:
Thank you. I have implemented a basic java binding for the main functionalities of Octomap, so I hope integrate to integrate Octomap in my planner.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-05-13**:
If you are happy with the bindings, these would be nice to package in the core rosjava repos - perhaps rosjava_extras.